# Curve extruded with geometry nodes looks weird (normals wrong?)

Tags: geometry-nodes, extrude

I added a Bezier curve to my project and then tried to extrude it into a solid object using geometry nodes like this:

[image]

However, the result looks like this. The shape is what I expected, but the shading is all wrong. (It looks similarly weird in a rendered view.)

[image]

I guess this is because the normals are not correct, or some similar issue. What is causing this, and how can I fix it within the geometry nodes setup?

I am also happy to learn about alternative ways to achieve a similar result (using geometry nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need probably **Set Shade Smooth** node and uncheck?

[image]
[image]

---

For smoothing just a curvy part and keep sharp edges you can [follow this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259781), that is using native **Auto Smooth** feature, but there are some rules to get it work.

Or you can try a **Split Edges** node to get the same result (that can work in some scenarios) ...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah, great, thanks. I'd tried toggling shade smooth in the GUI but hadn't thought of doing it in geometry nodes.